# How I can save all the names of my tables into a new table from sql?

Tags: sql-server

I have a huge database in Sql-Server and I need to get all the names of the tables into one new table that I have made. This can be done?
I appreciate your help.
The new table has the fields ID, TableName, Status. Id is the identity and status for now will be 1, not null

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use this query below to get all tables name from your database

```
SELECT name FROM sys.tables
```

Then you can do a insert query like -

```
insert into newtable(name) select * from sys.tables
```

Comment: I just edit the description. How do I get all the information in a column?

Comment: My query would look like:
`INSERT INTO Tables (TableName, Estatus) SELECT name FROM sys.tables, 1`
but it does not work

Comment: I solved it. Allow nulls in Status and insert the data, then I did the update status field and changed to allow nulls.
Thank you